# How to customize the nautilus-actions?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I installed nautilus-actions and nautilus-actions-extra and they have lots of cool and useful stuff for Linux noobs like me who can't be bothered to learn the terminal, but my Nautilus context menu doesn't fit on the screen anymore.

I read that you could choose which commands to show using the nautilus actions configuration tool, but when I start it, it shows a blank actions list. There is an import assistant, except I have no clue what kind of files I'm supposed to import and where from.

How do I get my installed actions to show?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Press Super-Key (Windows Key) and type: `gksu nautilus-actions-config-tool`

The Nautilus-Actions-Extra package provides quite a large list of actions, but you can remove (or reorganize) some of them if you want. To do this, launch Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool as root. See for more detailed infos [Nautilus Actions Extra](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/nautilus-actions-extra-pack-of-useful.html)

Comment: I've read that already, and running the tool as root still gives a blank list. There's also no "root" in the title bar, like in that screenshot, though that's an older version.